# Linux iptables forward from ip1:port1 to ip2:port2

Tags: linux, iptables

I connect thought tunnel to other machine like this:
    ssh user@ip -L2000:192.168.64.88:80

So on my local machine I want to configure iptables that way like I have a "native" access to 192.168.64.88 address. I mean when I enter on web browser http:// 192.168.64.88 iptables will redirect to my localhost port 2000 which is connected to remote machine.

How can I configure iptables to redirect from 192.168.64.88 port 80 to localhost port 2000?

I tried this but with no luck:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.64.88 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2000
```

On mac os x machine I do it like this:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 192.168.64.88 alias
sudo ipfw add fwd 127.0.0.1,2000 tcp from me to 192.168.64.88 dst-port 80
```

But I don't know how to do this on linux machine.

Comment: related http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: I guess I miss something like "alias"

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.64.88 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:2000
```

IE your command was pretty much correct.  I'm guessing another rule is being matched first so this rule is never being hit.  Using -I instead of -A puts this rule at the beginning rather then end of the table.